# THREE.js spread particles evenly in complex model

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm looking for a way to achive similar effect to this http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry  . My main concern is about possibility of even distribution of particles(or vectors) like in example above, but in a complex model loaded from Blender.

- Is it possible?
- If it is, should model from Blender be prepered in any particular way?

I'm quite new to 3d/three.js and I'm totally stuck with this problem. Any hints?

Comment: An alternate approach is to use the three.js method `THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( geometry, n )`, which returns points on the faces (i.e., surface) of the geometry.

Comment: I can't find the randomPointsInGeometry method in the documentation nor the source, am I missing something?

Comment: @Michał Klim did you find a solution, example?

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly spawn points in the geometry bounding box and than check if point belongs to geometry, respawn if not.

Checking if point belongs to geometry is computationally expensive operation. You can use Binary space partitioning (BSP) https://github.com/electricessence/ThreeBSP or voxelising

If your geometry does not have holes you can try to use raycasting to check point belongingness

Another cheaper approach @WestLangley mentiond in comments you can use `THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry()` from examples/js/utils/GeometryUtils.js to distribute points on the faces.